# Changing HTML-TITLE for web application with NGINX

Tags: nginx, proxy, web-applications, html

There are some web applications which are running on my server. Most of them use their own small server, which are bound to localhost. So for access them, I am using NGINX which runs as a proxy.

Now, there is a web app which has a hard coded HTML-TITLE. So the problem is that I cannot change it to the name of my site.

My idea: If NGINX is running as a proxy, all data has to pass NGINX so I am able to change this TITLE befor the server sends the data to the client. Because this web application only use on site, the traffic will not be huge so it can take time to change the TITLE.

Does anyone has an idea how to modify this? I only know how to chnage HEADER settings...

Comment: From that possible duplicate, check out ngx_http_sub_module - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

Comment: Is there any method without compiling NGINX myself?